# xsd validation to allow unexpected elements

Tags: xsd

I need your help :'(
I have a problem with XSD validation, It returns error with Unexpected elements. But i want to allow and skip any unexpected elements. I try to use `<xs:any>`but its not allowed under `<xs:all>` and `<xs:element ref` doesn't work, I have no idea how to fix it :

```
<xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
            <xs:any processContents="lax" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:integer" />
            <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element ref="adress" />
            <xs:element ref="phone" />
        </xs:all>
```

It returns error for example when I got unexpected elements "gender". 
DO you know which tag can be help ? or any solutions. Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1):

Change `<xs:all>` to `<xs:sequence>` as specified in http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_any.asp it will work.

```
<xs:element name="person">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:any minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Surendra Kongurootu :) But the point is I dont want to use <xs:sequence>.

Comment: Sorry, to post after such a long time. That does not comply if the elements inside "xs:sequence" are in a different order than the one stated. Is there any way to accomplish both things? (no particular order in addition to one or more unexpected elements in the list)